# Xamarin c# can not call Google Gson FromJson

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, gson

I am trying to call  the method "fromJSon" of Google Gson (in C#, Xamarin), but I am receiving following Error : "Arguement 2, cannot convert Java.Lang.Object to Java.Lang.Class".

Here is my Source code of the relevant Part :

```
...
        HomePojo mHomePojo = null;
        Gson mGson = new Gson();

        try
        {
            GoogleGson.JsonObject dataObject = jObject.GetAsJsonObject(AppGlobal.TAG_JSON_DATA_OBJECT);
            Java.Lang.Object clazz = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(HomePojo));
            mHomePojo = mGson.FromJson(dataObject.AsJsonObject, clazz);

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
        }
        return mHomePojo;
...
```

It is showing "Arguement 2, cannot convert Java.Lang.Object to Java.Lang.Class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a *ObjectTypeHelper* class.

```
public static class ObjectTypeHelper
    {
      public static T Cast<T>(this Java.Lang.Object obj) where T : class
        {
            var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
            return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
        }
    }
```

And *HomePojo* class Should inherit from *ObjectTypeHelper* ,then have a try with follow code:

```
GoogleGson.JsonObject dataObject = jObject.GetAsJsonObject(AppGlobal.TAG_JSON_DATA_OBJECT);
mHomePojo = mGson.FromJson(dataObject.AsJsonObject, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(HomePojo)).Cast<HomePojo>();;
```

If not working, maybe Gson is still compatible with xamarin android.

**WorkaRound** :

Using ***Newtonsoft.Json*** to deserialize your json object.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public List<string> options { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should be able to deserialize your json:

```
List<RootObject> myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Comment: The Workaround worked. Simple solution. Sorry for the delayed Acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variable as `Java.Lang.Class` so that it matches the parameter type.

Comment: Did that. Now it is saying --- can not implicitly convert type from "Java.Lang.Object" to "com.*.HomePojo".